# Android main thread getting locked in db operation

Tags: android, sqlcipher

My application uses sqlcipher database. It uses cursor loader to query data from db

I am running into ANR. See below ANR trace

What I am trying to understand here is that why would a main thread which is trying to close the cursor get blocked on itself. This issue happens randomly and I have not yet figured out a reproducible scenario. I am doubting if this is locking issue associated with sqlcipher's cursor implementation.

```
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415979a0 self=0x4000b010
    | sysTid=9804 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075102172
    | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=3670 stm=710 core=1
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)

waiting on (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main) at
java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231) at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:810) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:843) at
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1173) at
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:198) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:259) at 
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:460) at 
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.close(SQLiteProgram.java:294) at 
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.close(SQLiteQuery.java:136) at 
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:510) at
android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49) at 
android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49) at 
android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1860) at
android.database.MergeCursor.close(MergeCursor.java:175) at 
android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49) at 
android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:117) at 
android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:43)
```

I have been trying to debug the issue, but have no idea where to start with

can somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs, the only reason I can think of that could have triggered an ANR is:

As far as i know, usually in Java every thread is associated with 2 components. One being Program counter and the other being Garbage Collector. So every thread will have a gc monitor happening throughout.

**waiting on (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main) at**

VMThreads are ideally used to handle this aspect of monitoring gc, almost parallelly. So what i could think of, for your scenario, is SQLiteDatabase is trying to acquire a lock but is unable to because VMThread is holding the lock, unreleased yet (may be due to some major GC op), thus waiting for vmthread to release the lock.

You might want to check your main log dump which has gc activities logged, that might give you a better picture as to why gc was hogging this threads CPU time so much and then app profiling may help.
Jus check.